# Can you communicate via bluetooth when a phone is in standby?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

is it possible to create an iphone-app, which can communicate with other iphones (with the app installed) even if the app is running in the background or the iphone is locked (=standby).
there is an app called "Bluetooth", which establishes a connection, but looses it as soon as the app is closed or the iphone in standby.
hope i am not too confusing in my explanations

Comment: Google search terms (or subject tags) don't make good titles. Ask what you want in the title of your question.